# Show View State checkbox on User record is missing

Tags: user-record, viewstate

I have one client where the "Show View State in Development Mode" checkbox field is missing on the User detail screen, so I can't enable View State.  The user has a full Salesforce license and is a sys admin.  I can enable the Development Mode checkbox but that doesn't give me the View State tab on the footer.

When I look into other clients' instances, they do display the "Show View State" checkbox in the User record.

These are all production instances and all in Winter 19.  I've done some searching but can't find any explanation as to why the checkbox is missing.  Has anyone seen this before?

**Update**: The VF page in the original instance does have an `<apex:form>` tag and it's using a custom controller.

Comment: Not sure why the checkbox is missing, but Since the [view state](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_tools_edit_toolbar.htm) is linked to form data, the View State tab only appears if your page contains an <apex:form> tag. In addition, the View State tab displays only on pages using custom controllers or controller extensions.

Comment: @codeyinthecloud ah thanks for the additional info, I updated my question.

Comment: you're welcome. There is a simiar question with no answer for reference. Read [Enable "Show View State" option missing on User Details page](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000XhMQQA0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to contact Salesforce Support and their Tier 3 level enabled the Show View State field.